# Bootstrap data-affix/position-fixed col overlapping other col

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with my bootstrap website. I have my site setup like so:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-9" style="text-align:left;padding-top: 2%">
         Some content
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3" style="position:fixed">
         Scrolling Sidebar
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I have been trying to wrap my head around why the side bar is floated all the way to the left and is a col-3 but with a larger container so it's much larger on my screen. Has anyone seen something like this before?

Comment: Please post the exact Bootstrap version and any other custom CSS associated with these components.  Also, do you have any Javascript manipulating your DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why there is overlapping conent is that when you make something position:fixed - it takes it out of the page flow and the remaining contents take its place. You need to explicitly set the width when it is fixed. In the following i am using a class "is-fixed" to set the fixe position styling.

```
<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-9" style="text-align:left;padding-top: 2%">
             Some content
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3 is-fixed">
             Scrolling Sidebar
             </div>
          </div>
 </div>

//css style for element that is fixed
.is-fixed {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width:200px; // or whatever
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to basically manually position my entire div

Comment: Your'e welcome - happy to help. Two other suggestions - you dont need to set text alignment to the left - that is default (unless you are setting it somehere else) and second - its better to not have the styles inline but in a style rule in the css (eg: div.left-column {padding-top: 2%} or somthing )